# UIButton not responding when it overlaps another UIButton

Tags: iphone, uikit, uibutton

I have a `UIViewController` called `MyViewController`. MyViewController's view has an `UIButton` called `MyFirstButton` as a subview. Then MyViewController's view adds another subview called `MySubView`. `MySubView` is placed directly over `MyFirstButton`, so `MyFirstButton` isn't seen. `MySubView` in its turn has an `UIButton` called `MySecondButton` as a subview.

The issue is - if MySecondButton's frame overlaps MyFirstButton's frame, then `MySecondButton` doesn't respond.

I tried to fix it by setting `userInteractionEnabled` to NO for MyViewController's view and YES for `MySubView`, but it didn't help. The button still not responding. How do i enable a button which is located over another?

Answer (score 0):

You cant use the action for that particular MyFirstButton which is under MySecondButton... I dnt think this can be done .. what you can actually do is hide MySecondButton on its click to reveal the MYFirstButton and then on the MYFirstButton click have its action performed and reveal the MYSecondButton again on top of the first one :) likewise play hidden with the subviews 2...

Comment: i need to use secondButton's action not first

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIButton *firstButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [firstButton setTitle:@"first" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    firstButton.frame=CGRectMake(40, 70, 80, 80);
    [firstButton addTarget:self action:@selector(firstButtonClicked) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:firstButton];

    UIView *view=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)];
    [firstButton addSubview:view];
    UIButton *secondButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [secondButton setTitle:@"second" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     secondButton.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80);
    [secondButton addTarget:self action:@selector(secondButtonClicked) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [view addSubview:secondButton];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
-(void)firstButtonClicked {
    NSLog(@"first");
}
-(void)secondButtonClicked {
    NSLog(@"second");
}
```

Comment: they both don't respond so both methods will not get called

Comment: it's too much of code plus frames are set in nib files so it won't make a lot of sense i'm afraid